# How to convert zoom value to magnifcation?

Tags: android, google-glass

In my Android app, I need to convert the current zoom value of the camera to magnification. I am trying to understand what getMaxZoom() corresponds to in terms of magnification. For example, my camera has a maximum zoom value of 60. It obviously doesn't mean that the magnification is 60 times the original view. There must be a conversion that one can apply. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of these as the possible zoom stops that the camera can support. The actual magnification is available through [getZoomRatios()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getZoomRatios()), which provide a list of what magnification is available for each level in 1/100 increments.

So if `getMaxZoom()` returns 5, the call to `getZoomRatios()` might return a list with the following values:

```
100, 150, 200, 225, 250
```

meaning that zoom level 0 is magnified 1x, zoom level 1 is magnified 1.5x, zoom level 2 is magnified 2x, zoom level 3 is 2.25x, and zoom level 4 magnified 2.5x.